# In bracket editor, some keys got changed. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, editor, adobe-brackets

Bracket Editor Version: Release 1.3 build 1.3.0-16022

OS: window 7

In the Bracket editor '@', '#', and '"' symbols are not working directly.

when I press shift + 2,  it prints " instead of @. 
when I press shift + ',  it prints @ instead of ". 
when I press shift + 3,  it prints £ instead of #.

Is there a way to fix this to default keys?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Some config files got corrupted. Uninstalled & then re-installed it. working fine now.